# SQL Server: executing dynamic/inline sql table name within EXEC and passing geometry as geometry parameter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, dynamic, exec, inline

I'm trying to execute an inline SQL statement within a stored procedure. I'm working with SQL Server 2008.

The problem is that I can't execute the first inline statement (with `WHERE` clause). It crashes because the string within `EXEC(...)` is dynamically created and all concatenated variables must be of type `varchar`.

Error that appears when calling procedure:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near 'ORDER'.

The procedure looks like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE loadMyRows
  @table_name    nvarchar(50),
  @bounding_box  varchar(8000)
AS
BEGIN
  -- *********************************** COMMENT *********************************
  -- ** This two code lines are correct and will return true (1) or false (0),  **
  -- ** but they doesn't work within inline EXEC(...)                           **
  --DECLARE @bb geometry = geometry::STGeomFromText(@bounding_box, 4326);
  --select TOP(5) wkt.STWithin(@bb) AS 'bool'
  -- *********************************** COMMENT *********************************

IF @bounding_box <> ''
BEGIN
    DECLARE @bb geometry = geometry::STGeomFromText(@bounding_box, 4326);

    EXEC(   
        'SELECT TOP (' + @row_limit + ') * ' +
        'FROM ' + @real_table_name + ' ' +
        'WHERE wkt.STWithin('+@bb+') ' + -- <-- doesn't work :-(
      -- 'WHERE wkt.STWithin(geometry::STGeomFromText('''+@bounding_box+''', 4326)) ' +
      -- ^^ doesn't work, too :-(
        'ORDER BY id ASC '
    );
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    EXEC(
        'SELECT TOP (' + @row_limit + ') * ' +
        'FROM ' + @real_table_name + ' ' +
        'ORDER BY id ASC'
    );
END
END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a working solution for this problem. The way the MSDN showed me was http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms175170.aspx. There's written:

> [...] the string is executed as its own self-contained batch.

That let me know, if I want to execute a dynamic statement with a table variable as string, it's the same as I would execute the query without the `EXECUTE` command, like:

```
SELECT TOP(@row_limit) *
FROM @real_table_name
WHERE ...
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

And this would probably not work for the table name.

So, if I write instead:

```
DECLARE @sql_statement nvarchar(MAX) = 'SELECT TOP(@limit) * 
                                        FROM ' + @real_table_name + ' 
                                        ORDER BY id ASC';

-- declaration of parameters for above sql                              
DECLARE @sql_param_def nvarchar(MAX) = '@limit int';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql_statement, @sql_param_def, @limit = @row_limit;
```

Then, this would work. This is because I define the @sql_statement simply as a concatenated string which will just resolve the dynamic table name at runtime to a string with the name of the real existing table. The @limit parameter is untouched and is still a parameter.

If we then execute the batch we only must pass a value for the @limit parameter and it works!

For the geometry parameter it works in the same way:

```
DECLARE @bb geometry = geometry::STGeomFromText(@bounding_box, 4326);
SET @sql_statement = 'SELECT TOP(@limit) * 
                      FROM ' + @real_table_name + ' 
                      WHERE wkt.STWithin(@geobb) = 1 
                      ORDER BY id ASC';
-- NOTE: This ' = 1' must be set to avoid my above described error (STWithin doesn't return a BOOLEAN!!)

-- declaration of parameters for above sql
SET @sql_param_def = '@limit int, @geobb geometry';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql_statement, @sql_param_def, @limit = @row_limit, @geobb = @bb;
```

Hope this was clear ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
create proc usp_insert_Proc_Into_temp
@tempTable nvarchar(10) output
as
begin

 set @tempTable = '##temp' 
 declare @query nvarchar(200)
 --Select statement
 set @query = 'select  1 as A,2 as B, 3 as C into'+ ' '+@tempTable+''
 exec(@query)


end

go


declare @tempTable nvarchar(10)
exec usp_insert_Proc_Into_temp @tempTable output
exec('select *  from' + ' '+ @tempTable+'')

exec ('drop table'+ ' '+@tempTable+'')
```